# Loop For User Input and Adding summation of Dice Rolls

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to make a game with JavaScript but I am stuck. I cannot figure out how to take the rolls from the dice and put it into a table to count how many rolls were made before the player runs out of money, and the other 3 requirements at the end of the rules::::: any advice would be super helpful!

### The rules

- As long as there is money, play the game.
- Each round, the program rolls a virtual pair of dice for the user.
- If the sum of the 2 dice is equal to 7, the player wins $4
  otherwise, the player loses $1.

The program asks the user how many dollars they have to bet. 
If the starting bet is less than or equal to 0, display an error message.
When the user clicks the Play button, the program then rolls the dice repeatedly until all the money is gone.

Hint: Use a loop construct to keep playing until the money is gone.

Hint: We created a rollDice() function in the Rolling Dice exercise.

- The program keeps track of how many rolls were taken before the money ran out.
- The program keeps track of the maximum amount of money held by the player.
- The program keeps track of how many rolls were taken at the point when the user held the most money.

I couldn't get my code to paste properly so I've added a snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title> Lucky Sevens </title>
<style>
</style>

<script>
<!--reset form field to natural state-->
function clearErrors() {
    for (var loopCounter = 0;
        loopCounter < document.forms["bet"].elements.length;
        loopCounter++) {
        if (document.forms["bet"].elements[loopCounter]
           .parentElement.className.indexOf("has-") != -1) {

            document.forms["bet"].elements[loopCounter]
               .parentElement.className = "form-group";
        }
    }
}
<!--clear form fields-->
function resetForm() {
  clearErrors();
  document.forms["bet"]["num1"].value = "";
  document.getElementById("results").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("submitButton").innerText = "Submit";
  document.forms["bet"]["num1"].focus();
  alert("You have reset the form and will lose all progress.");
}
<!--verify user input is expected-->
function validateItems() {
  clearErrors();
  var num1 = document.forms["bet"]["num1"].value;
  if (num1 == "" || isNaN(num1)) {
      alert("Num1 must be filled in with a number.");
      document.forms["bet"]["num1"]
         .parentElement.className = "form-group has-error";
      document.forms["bet"]["num1"].focus();
      return false;
  }
  if (num1 >= 11) {
      alert("Bet must be between $1-$10");
      document.forms["bet"]["num1"]
         .parentElement.className = "form-group has-error"
      document.forms["bet"]["num1"].focus();
      return false;
  }
  if (num1 <= 0) {
      alert("Bet must be between $1-$10");
      document.forms["bet"]["num1"]
         .parentElement.className = "form-group has-error"
      document.forms["bet"]["num1"].focus();
      return false;
  }

 document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("submitButton").innerText = "Roll Again";
 document.getElementById("startingBet").innerText = num1;

 return false;
}


function rollDice() {
  var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
  var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var d1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var d2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
  die1.innerHTML = d1;
  die2.innerHTML = d2;
  status.innerHTML = "You rolled " + diceTotal + ".";
  if(diceTotal == 7) {
    status.innerHTML += " You win $4!";
  }
  if(diceTotal != 7){
    status.innerHTML += " You lose $1.";
  }

}
</script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Lucky Sevens</h1>
    <form name="bet" onsubmit="return validateItems();"
          onreset="resetForm();" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="num1">Starting Bet</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="num1">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" onclick="rollDice()" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

    </form>
    <h2 id="status" style="clear:left;"></h2>
    <div id="die1" class="dice">0</div>
    <div id="die2" class="dice">0</div>
    <hr />

    <table id="results" class="table table-striped" style="display:none;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Starting Bet</td>
                <td><span id="startingBet"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Rolls Before Going Broke</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Highest Amount Won</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Roll Count at Highest Amount Win</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```